# Flash CS6 not recognizing functions and packages

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm working on a 3D game for the Technology Student Association.

I am an amateur programmer, so this is probably why I'm having these problems. It started at first by adding a 3rd level, and Flash not recognizing the packages that the *private functions* are in. Please advise, here's the code:

```
package { 
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.*;

    public class Dungeon3D extends MovieClip {
        public var viewSprite:Sprite; // everything
        public var worldSprite:Sprite; // walls, ceiling, floor, coins

        // references to objects
        public var map:Map; // mc to use for wall and coin positions
        public var map2:Map2; // mc to use for wall and coin positions      
        public var squares:Array; // blocks on map
        public var worldObjects:Array; // walls and coins

        private var charPos:Point; // player location

        // keyboard input
        private var leftArrow, rightArrow, upArrow, downArrow: Boolean;

        // car direction and speed
        private var dir:Number = 90;
        private var speed:Number = 0;

        //mrb:  variables
        private var gameMode:String = "start";      
        public var playerObjects:Array;     
        private var gameScore:int;
        private var playerLives:int;        

        // start game
        public function startGame() {
            gameMode = "play";          
            playerObjects = new Array();
            gameScore = 0;
            playerLives = 3;
        }       
        public function startDungeon3D() {
            viewSprite = new Sprite();
            viewSprite.x = 275;
            viewSprite.y = 250;
            viewSprite.z = -500;
            addChild(viewSprite);

            // add an inner sprite to hold everything, lay it down
            worldSprite = new Sprite();
            viewSprite.addChild(worldSprite);
            worldSprite.rotationX = -90;

            // cover above with ceiling tiles
            for(var i:int=-5;i<5;i++) {
                for(var j:int=-6;j<1;j++) {
                    var ceiling:Ceiling = new Ceiling();
                    ceiling.x = i*200;
                    ceiling.y = j*200;
                    ceiling.z = -200; // above
                    worldSprite.addChild(ceiling);
                }
            }

            // cover below with floor tiles
            for(i=-5;i<5;i++) {
                for(j=-6;j<1;j++) {
                    var floor:Floor = new Floor();
                    floor.x = i*200;
                    floor.y = j*200;
                    floor.z = 0; // below
                    worldSprite.addChild(floor);
                }
            }

            // get the game map
            map = new Map();

            // look for squares in map, and put four walls in each spot
            // also move coins up and rotate them
            worldObjects = new Array();
            squares = new Array();
            for(i=0;i<map.numChildren;i++) {
                var object = map.getChildAt(i);
                //var mc = this.gamelevel.getChildAt(i);

                if (object is Square) {
                    // add four walls, one for each edge of square
                    addWall(object.x+object.width/2, object.y, object.width, 0);
                    addWall(object.x, object.y+object.height/2, object.height, 90);
                    addWall(object.x+object.width, object.y+object.height/2, object.height, 90);
                    addWall(object.x+object.width/2, object.y+object.height, object.width, 0);

                    // remember squares for collision detection
                    squares.push(object);

                } else if (object is Coin) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort

                } else if (object is Key) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort

                } else if (object is Chest) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort

                }  else if (object is Door) {
                    object.z = 77; // move up
                    object.rotationX = 90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort
                }
            }

            // keep track of virtual position of character
            charPos = new Point(0,0);

            // arrange all walls and coins for distance
            zSort();

            // respond to key events
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressedDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyPressedUp);

            // advance game
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveGame);
        }

        public function startDungeon3D2() {
        // create the world and center it
            viewSprite = new Sprite();
            viewSprite.x = 275;
            viewSprite.y = 250;
            viewSprite.z = -500;
            addChild(viewSprite);

            // add an inner sprite to hold everything, lay it down
            worldSprite = new Sprite();
            viewSprite.addChild(worldSprite);
            worldSprite.rotationX = -90;

            // cover above with ceiling tiles
            for(var i:int=-5;i<5;i++) {
                for(var j:int=-6;j<1;j++) {
                    var ceiling:Ceiling = new Ceiling();
                    ceiling.x = i*200;
                    ceiling.y = j*200;
                    ceiling.z = -200; // above
                    worldSprite.addChild(ceiling);
                }
            }

            // cover below with floor tiles
            for(i=-5;i<5;i++) {
                for(j=-6;j<1;j++) {
                    var floor:Floor = new Floor();
                    floor.x = i*200;
                    floor.y = j*200;
                    floor.z = 0; // below
                    worldSprite.addChild(floor);
                }
            }

            // get the game map
            map2 = new Map2();

            // look for squares in map, and put four walls in each spot
            // also move coins up and rotate them
            worldObjects = new Array();
            squares = new Array();
            for(i=0;i<map2.numChildren;i++) {
                var object = map2.getChildAt(i);
                //var mc = this.gamelevel.getChildAt(i);

                if (object is Square) {
                    // add four walls, one for each edge of square
                    addWall(object.x+object.width/2, object.y, object.width, 0);
                    addWall(object.x, object.y+object.height/2, object.height, 90);
                    addWall(object.x+object.width, object.y+object.height/2, object.height, 90);
                    addWall(object.x+object.width/2, object.y+object.height, object.width, 0);

                    // remember squares for collision detection
                    squares.push(object);

                } else if (object is Coin) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort

                } else if (object is Key) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort

                } else if (object is Chest) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort

                }  else if (object is Door) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort
                }
            }

        public function startDungeon3D3() {
        // create the world and center it
            viewSprite = new Sprite();
            viewSprite.x = 275;
            viewSprite.y = 250;
            viewSprite.z = -500;
            addChild(viewSprite);

            // add an inner sprite to hold everything, lay it down
            worldSprite = new Sprite();
            viewSprite.addChild(worldSprite);
            worldSprite.rotationX = -90;

            // cover above with ceiling tiles
            for(var i:int=-5;i<5;i++) {
                for(var j:int=-6;j<1;j++) {
                    var ceiling:Ceiling = new Ceiling();
                    ceiling.x = i*200;
                    ceiling.y = j*200;
                    ceiling.z = -200; // above
                    worldSprite.addChild(ceiling);
                }
            }

            // cover below with floor tiles
            for(i=-5;i<5;i++) {
                for(j=-6;j<1;j++) {
                    var floor:Floor = new Floor();
                    floor.x = i*200;
                    floor.y = j*200;
                    floor.z = 0; // below
                    worldSprite.addChild(floor);
                }
            }

            // get the game map
            map3 = new Map3();

            // cover below with floor tiles
            for(i=-5;i<5;i++) {
                for(j=-6;j<1;j++) {
                    var floor:Floor = new Floor();
                    floor.x = i*200;
                    floor.y = j*200;
                    floor.z = 0; // below
                    worldSprite.addChild(floor);
                }
            }

            // look for squares in map, and put four walls in each spot
            // also move coins up and rotate them
            worldObjects = new Array();
            squares = new Array();
            for(i=0;i<map3.numChildren;i++) {
                var object = map3.getChildAt(i);
                //var mc = this.gamelevel.getChildAt(i);

                if (object is Square) {
                    // add four walls, one for each edge of square
                    addWall(object.x+object.width/2, object.y, object.width, 0);
                    addWall(object.x, object.y+object.height/2, object.height, 90);
                    addWall(object.x+object.width, object.y+object.height/2, object.height, 90);
                    addWall(object.x+object.width/2, object.y+object.height, object.width, 0);

                    // remember squares for collision detection
                    squares.push(object);

                } else if (object is Coin) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort

                } else if (object is Key) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort

                } else if (object is Chest) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort

                }  else if (object is Door) {
                    object.z = -50; // move up
                    object.rotationX = -90; // turn to face player
                    worldSprite.addChild(object);
                    worldObjects.push(object); // add to array fo zSort
                }
            }
            // keep track of virtual position of character
            charPos = new Point(0,0);

            // arrange all walls and coins for distance
            zSort();

            // respond to key events
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressedDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyPressedUp);

            // advance game
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveGame);
        }       

        // add a vertical wall 
        public function addWall(x, y, len, rotation) {
            var wall:Wall = new Wall();
            wall.x = x;
            wall.y = y;
            wall.z = -wall.height/2;
            wall.width = len;
            wall.rotationX = 90;
            wall.rotationZ = rotation;
            worldSprite.addChild(wall);
            worldObjects.push(wall);
        }

        // set arrow variables to true
        public function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent) {
            if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                leftArrow = true;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                rightArrow = true;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                upArrow = true;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                downArrow = true;
            }
        }

        // set arrow variables to false
        public function keyPressedUp(event:KeyboardEvent) {
            if (event.keyCode == 37) {
                leftArrow = false;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                rightArrow = false;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                upArrow = false;
            } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                downArrow = false;
            }
        }

        private function turnPlayer(d) {

            // change direction
            dir += d;

            // rotate world to change view
            viewSprite.rotationY = dir-90;
        }

        // main game function
        public function moveGame(e) {

            // see if turning left or right
            var turn:Number = 0;
            if (leftArrow) {
                turn = 10;
            } else if (rightArrow) {
                turn = -10;
            }

            // turn
            if (turn != 0) {
                turnPlayer(turn);
            }

            // if up arrow pressed, then accelerate, otherwise decelerate
            speed = 0;
            if (upArrow) {
                speed = 10;
            } else if (downArrow) {
                speed = -10;
            }

            // move
            if (speed != 0) {
                movePlayer(speed);
            }

            // re-sort objects
            if ((speed != 0) || (turn != 0)) {
                zSort();
            }

            // see if any coins hit
            checkCoins();
            checkKey();
            checkChest();       
            checkDoor();
        }

        public function movePlayer(d) {
            // calculate current player area

            // make a rectangle to approximate space used by player
            var charSize:Number = 50; // approximate player size
            var charRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(charPos.x-charSize/2, charPos.y-charSize/2, charSize, charSize);

            // get new rectangle for future position of player
            var newCharRect:Rectangle = charRect.clone();
            var charAngle:Number = (-dir/360)*(2.0*Math.PI);
            var dx:Number = d*Math.cos(charAngle);
            var dy:Number = d*Math.sin(charAngle);
            newCharRect.x += dx;
            newCharRect.y += dy;

            // calculate new location
            var newX:Number = charPos.x + dx;
            var newY:Number = charPos.y + dy;

            // loop through squares and check collisions
            for(var i:int=0;i<squares.length;i++) {

                // get block rectangle, see if there is a collision
                var blockRect:Rectangle = squares[i].getRect(map);
                if (blockRect.intersects(newCharRect)) {

                    // horizontal push-back
                    if (charPos.x <= blockRect.left) {
                        newX +=  blockRect.left - newCharRect.right;
                    } else if (charPos.x >= blockRect.right) {
                        newX += blockRect.right - newCharRect.left;
                    }

                    // vertical push-back
                    if (charPos.y >= blockRect.bottom) {
                        newY +=  blockRect.bottom - newCharRect.top;
                    } else if (charPos.y <= blockRect.top) {
                        newY +=  blockRect.top - newCharRect.bottom;
                    }
                }

            }

            // move character position
            charPos.y = newY;
            charPos.x = newX;

            // move terrain to show proper view
            worldSprite.x = -newX;
            worldSprite.z = newY;
        }

        // spin coins and see if any have been hit
        private function checkCoins() { 
            // look at all objects
            for(var i:int=worldObjects.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
                // only look at coins
                if (worldObjects[i] is Coin) {
                    // spin it!
                    worldObjects[i].rotationZ += 10;
                    // check distance from character
                    var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(charPos.x-worldObjects[i].x,2)+Math.pow(charPos.y-worldObjects[i].y,2));
                    // if close enough, remove coin
                    if (dist < 50) {
                        worldSprite.removeChild(worldObjects[i]);
                        worldObjects.splice(i,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // spin coins and see if any have been hit
        private function checkKey() {   
            // look at all objects
            for(var i:int=worldObjects.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
                // only look at coins
                if (worldObjects[i] is Key) {
                    // spin it!
                    worldObjects[i].rotationZ += 10;
                    // check distance from character
                    var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(charPos.x-worldObjects[i].x,2)+Math.pow(charPos.y-worldObjects[i].y,2));
                    // if close enough, remove coin
                    if (dist < 50) {
                        getObject(i);  // mrb:  call to getobject                       
                        worldSprite.removeChild(worldObjects[i]);
                        worldObjects.splice(i,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }       

        // spin coins and see if any have been hit
        private function checkChest() {
            // look at all objects
            for(var i:int=worldObjects.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
                // only look at coins
                if (worldObjects[i] is Chest) {
                    // spin it!
                    worldObjects[i].rotationZ += 10;
                    // check distance from character
                    var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(charPos.x-worldObjects[i].x,2)+Math.pow(charPos.y-worldObjects[i].y,2));
                    // if close enough and have the key end the level; don't remove if no key
                    if (dist < 50) {
                        getObject(i);  // mrb:  call to getobject   
                        //worldSprite.removeChild(worldObjects[i]);
                        //worldObjects.splice(i,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   

        // spin coins and see if any have been hit
        private function checkDoor() {
            // look at all objects
            for(var i:int=worldObjects.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
                // only look at coins
                if (worldObjects[i] is Door) {
                    // spin it!
                    worldObjects[i].rotationZ += 10;
                    // check distance from character
                    var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(charPos.x-worldObjects[i].x,2)+Math.pow(charPos.y-worldObjects[i].y,2));
                    // if close enough and have the key end the level; don't remove if no key
                    if (dist < 50) {
                        getObject(i);  // mrb:  call to getobject   
                        //worldSprite.removeChild(worldObjects[i]);
                        //worldObjects.splice(i,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   


        // player collides with objects
        public function getObject(objectNum:int) {
            // award points for treasure
            if (worldObjects[objectNum] is Treasure) {
                //var pb:PointBurst = new PointBurst(map,100,worldObjects[objectNum].x,worldObjects[objectNum].y);
                //gamelevel.removeChild(otherObjects[objectNum]);
                //otherObjects.splice(objectNum,1);
                //addScore(100);

            // got the key, add to inventory
            } else if (worldObjects[objectNum] is Key) {
                //pb = new PointBurst(gamelevel,"Got Key!" ,otherObjects[objectNum].x,otherObjects[objectNum].y);
                playerObjects.push("Key");
                trace(playerObjects.indexOf("Key"));
                //gamelevel.removeChild(otherObjects[objectNum]);
                //otherObjects.splice(objectNum,1);

            // hit the door, end level if hero has the key
            } else if (worldObjects[objectNum] is Door) {
                if (playerObjects.indexOf("Key") == -1) return;  // i don't have the key
                if (worldObjects[objectNum].currentFrame == 1) {  // i got the key  
                    worldObjects[objectNum].gotoAndPlay("open");            
                    levelComplete();
                }

            // got the chest, game won, if hero has the key
            } else if (worldObjects[objectNum] is Chest) {
                if (playerObjects.indexOf("Key") == -1) return;
                trace(worldObjects[objectNum].currentFrame);
                if (worldObjects[objectNum].currentFrame == 1) {
                    worldObjects[objectNum].gotoAndStop("open");
                    gameComplete();
                }
            }
        }

        // level over, bring up dialog
        public function levelComplete() {
            gameMode = "done";
            var dialog:Dialog = new Dialog();
            dialog.x = 175;
            dialog.y = 100;
            addChild(dialog);
            dialog.message.text = "Level Complete!";
        }           

        // game over, bring up dialog
        public function gameComplete() {
            gameMode = "gameover";
            var dialog:Dialog = new Dialog();
            dialog.x = 175;
            dialog.y = 100;
            addChild(dialog);
            dialog.message.text = "You Got the Treasure!";
        }

        // dialog button clicked
        public function clickDialogButton(event:MouseEvent) {
            removeChild(MovieClip(event.currentTarget.parent));

            // new life, restart, or go to next level
            if (gameMode == "dead") {
                // reset hero
                //showLives();
                //hero.mc.x = hero.startx;
                //hero.mc.y = hero.starty;
                gameMode = "play";
            } else if (gameMode == "gameover") {
                cleanUp();
                gotoAndStop("start");
            } else if (gameMode == "done") {
                cleanUp();
                nextFrame();
            }

            // give stage back the keyboard focus
            stage.focus = stage;
        }               

        // clean up game
        public function cleanUp() {
            //removeChild(gamelevel);
            //this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,gameLoop);
            //stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownFunction);
            //stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpFunction);

            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyPressedDown);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyPressedUp);
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveGame);          
            removeChild(viewSprite);            
        }           

        // sort all objects so the closest ones are highest in the display list
        private function zSort() {
            var objectDist:Array = new Array();
            for(var i:int=0;i<worldObjects.length;i++) {
                var z:Number = worldObjects[i].transform.getRelativeMatrix3D(root).position.z;
                objectDist.push({z:z,n:i});
            }
            objectDist.sortOn( "z", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING );
            for(i=0;i<objectDist.length;i++) {
                worldSprite.addChild(worldObjects[objectDist[i].n]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

These are the errors im getting now, even though the code IS there. The file name IS Dungeon3D.as

C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 217  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 324  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 337  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 350  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 362  1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 372  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 412  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 465  1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 484  1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 504  1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 524  1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 545  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 581  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 591  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 601  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 624  1114: The public attribute can only be used inside a package.
C:\Users\school\Desktop\Dungeon3DV3\Dungeon3D.as, Line 637  1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.

Whenever i change where something is in the code itself, i still get the same errors. Flash screw up? Or is the code being drawn from a different folder?

Comment: Use the [**`edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41988869/edit) button to add relevant details. Give an example of one code line that causes error and what is the error message? How are you importing & instancing the class? Does it help if you have `public function Dungeon3D()` existing (even if no code inside the `{  }` braces)? Is the file exactly called `Dungeon3D.as` (case sensitive)?...

Answer (score 0):

You missed `}` after `startDungeon3D2()` method. Add it in line number 214.